# Angular2 :Appending ID in the URL with get request

Tags: angular, routes

I have a page which displays a list of questions. When I click on view question I need to display the details of the question. I am doing it by passing the ID of the question in the router and when navigating to the questions detail page I need to get that question ID and append it to a get request. But when I append it the error in the question details page as error Response with status: 500 Internal Server Error for URL:

When navigating to the questions details page in the browser it shows the question ID as follows http://localhost:4200/question-fullview/5a4e6f2d0623e0086ed9e890. But it still displays the above error.

QuestionFullview.component.ts

```
export class QuestionFullviewComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public post: any[] = []
  public id: any;

  private sub: any;
  public accountDetails: any = {}
  constructor(private api: ApiServiceProvider, private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id']; 
      this.api.get("/posts/" + this.id, true)
        .subscribe((data) => {

          this.post = data.data
          console.log("This is the post data:", data)

        }, (err) => {
          alert("error " + err);
        })

    });
}
}
```

Comment: you need to check your backend code

Comment: 500 error is coming from your server. It doesn't like `GET /posts/{id}` for some reason